# Which verb is used to describe a person who is responsible and organising for doing something?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to use a verb to describe a person who is responsible for doing something, and the person is also the leader, organizer, or initiator of doing a project or something.

Checking the dictionary, it seems I can't say:

> He leads to build this website.

So, my question is that is there any verb to describe the meaning as above?
For example:

> He [verb] (to) build/building this website.

Feel appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A verb that can take on the several meanings expressed in the question is [**engineer**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/engineer#h2):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1** : to lay out, construct, or manage as an engineer
>   // *engineer* a bridge
>   **2 a** : to contrive or plan out usually with more or less subtle skill and craft
>   // *engineer* a business deal
>   **2 b** : to guide the course of
>   // *engineer* a rally

Somebody who *engineers* something is generally somebody who plans or initiates it, and is often also the person who oversees it to completion.

---

Using this word, the sentence in the question would become the following:

> He is *engineering* this website.

In that sentence, as with most involving *engineer*, there is no need to also use the verb *build*; *engineer* includes the sense of *build*, so adding it would be redundant.

Comment: I don't think engineer is an exact fit even if it's in a similar area. In a technical context (software, architecture/building, product design, etc), it refers to someone who's specifically responsible for the technical side of the design, rather than the high-level vision or overall control. And in non-technical contexts there's something a bit nefarious or manipulative about it, as in sense 2a you give.

Comment: @StuartF How is a website not technical?

Comment: Is a book technical? Is a magazine? It depends on the context. And if you're looking at a website from a technical point of view, the engineer would most likely be the person who writes the software or maintains the hardware, not the person who has overall control over content.

Comment: @StuartF Anybody who creates and maintains a website will be doing something technical. Just as a *publisher* of a book will be doing something technical. The content placed *on* the website (or in a book) might not be considered technical—assuming a distinction is made between technical and artistic. And if you're *building* something, as in the question, that's technical.

Answer (score 0):

As in:

> He authored this website.

to **author** verb  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/author)

> To write or construct (an electronic document or system): authored the
>   company's website.

An **author** (v. a writer) is an originator or creator, involved in a piece of a work from start to finish and generating the ideas behind it.

Comment: I can tolerate “he authored this website” but not “he authored the building this website”.

Comment: @AntonSherwood my bad!

Answer (score 0):

> He is **in charge of** building the website.
>   He **heads** the building of the website.

These do *not* imply that he initiated the project, only that he is its manager.

> The website **is his baby**.

This is a joking way of saying that he conceived it, he is in charge of the project, and he might react irrationally if the project is threatened.

Comment: I thought of a word closer to what the OP wants, but it had fled my mind by the time I started writing my answer.

Comment: Thanks, head seems to fit

Answer (score 0):

Would Orchestrated fit the bill?

Answer (score 0):

Creator

He is the creator of the website. He came up with the idea, he built it, or caused it to be built, he organises others to do it also.

Creator, definition

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/creator

Answer (score 0):

[Spearheaded](https://www.pongoresume.com/blogPosts/152/5-power-words-to-make-your-resume-get-noticed.cfm), as recommended as a strong word to use in resumes:

> To spearhead means to be the leader of something. But more important is the word's connotation. This word just oozes leadership, taking charge, and being a self-starter. And employers like any or all of those qualities in an employee. This word is especially helpful if you took charge of a project that delivered noticeable results.

For example:

[4 women spearheaded building the rocket stage set to launch the first woman to the Moon in 2024](https://parkbench.com/index.php/news/4-women-spearheaded-building-the-rocket-stage-set-to-launch-the-first-woman-to-the-moon-in-2024)